# One Dimensional Perlin noise vs Multi-Dimensional

Tags: java, perlin-noise

I am reading through a book called "The Nature of Coding" and I am working on porting the examples from Processing.js to Regular old Java. The example I am on uses the following method call in processing...

```
noise(x)
```

I noticed this [class](http://cs.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) provided by Perlin himself, however, it is three dimensional. Can I just do something like this to make it one dimensional (seems too easy)...

```
static public double noise(double x) {
    return noise(x, 0, 0);
}
```

Or is there some other changes I have to make?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, you should avoid doing that. 3D Perlin noise is 7 or 8 times as expensive as 1D Perlin noise. You'd be better off reimplementing the 1D function, because it's very simple. If I'm not mistaken:

```
static public double noise(double x) {
   int X = (int)Math.floor(x) & 255;
   x -= Math.floor(x);
   double u = fade(x);
   return lerp(u, grad(p[X  ], x  ),
                  grad(p[X+1], x-1));
}

static double grad(int hash, double x) {
   return ((hash&1) == 0 ? x : -x);
}
```

Comment: So I do notice some values in the previous version that look like they merge values, When I move to 2D do I have to create those merged values as well I am refering basically to...int A = p[X] + Y, AA = p[A] + Z, AB = p[A + 1] + Z, // HASH COORDINATES
               // OF
  B = p[X + 1] + Y, BA = p[B] + Z, BB = p[B + 1] + Z; // THE 8 CUBE
               // CORNERS,

Comment: The purpose of these `p[...p[...]]` constructs is to shuffle `X`, `Y` and `Z` in order to generate a pseudo-random hash number. In 1D you only have `X` so `p[X]` and `p[X+1]` are enough to generate the hash.

Answer (score 10):

Noise along any of the axes will be consistent noise. Just imagine you're flying through a cloud of noise sampling a single line of data.

So **yes**, `return noise(x, 0, 0);` is exactly like traveling along a single line of noise inside a cloud of noise. You'll be traveling along the line that represents the x axis. You could even do `return noise(x, x, x);` and travel diagonally through the noise if you wanted to. The point being, as long as you're moving linearly through the noise you'll get consistent noise with consistent values of `x`.

Comment: Can you expand this a little bit? For example the noise method in Processing does return a constant based on the x value passed to it, but the value does in fact change as x changes. Also you never really said if my implementation is correct with the 0s or not.

Comment: The word wasn't constant, it was _consistent_ - what Byte56 is saying is that any 1-dimensional 'slice' of a proper 3-dimensional noise function will be equivalent to a 1-dimensional noise function.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks, I was actually confused by that "constant" comment and your comment makes it clear now.

Comment: (Also, I should note that 'noise along any of the axes will be consistent' is a goal, but not always a reality - IIRC there are some bad implementations of Perlin noise out there that show some very distinct axial inhomogeneity.)

Comment: Note that `noise(x, x, x)` will return noise with a frequency `sqrt(3)` larger than expected. And even when accounting for that, you will not get the same noise as `noise(x, 0, 0)` because of Perlin noise’s inherent anisotropy.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I wasn't intending to say that `noise(x,x,x)` would be the *same* noise as `noise(x,0,0)`, that that both would produce noise in a reliable way. Would traveling along the diagonal not produce consistent noise?

Comment: Yes, it would produce consistent, and actually arguably better noise. An arbitrary axis `noise(a*x,b*x,c*x)` would even be better in terms of artifact reduction than a pure diagonal.